# Expression Engine: Edit Control Panel Channel Table Columns

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

Hi I am trying to edit the view channel table pictured below
[image]

Is this possible to remove table columns and replace them with data from that channels field group?

Or would I have to make a module and create this view from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Zenbu addon:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu

Comment: lol, yeah that will probably do it, cheers. I was hoping to get my hands dirty in some code rather than buy another plugin, because "buy a plugin" seems to be the only answer to any EE problem. And after a while I feel this leaves the developer without a true understanding on how to manipulate EE

Comment: Keep in mind that all add-ons that people are directing you to are not magic - they are just code other people have written using the same [developer infrastructure](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/index.html) that is available to anyone using EE. You certainly could get your hands dirty and replicate the functionality of any of these add-ons, but my guess is that the time you would invest is worth more than the cost of the add-ons. :)